# Discord.js How can a bot join, move to a channel just by writing its name

Tags: discord.js

I've seen a lot of post but most of them use `channel(channelID)`, but how about choosing where to **move, join** for example, by simply writing the name of the channel and catch if the specific name is incorrect.

```
    if (command === 'join') {
        if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
        const voiceChannel = client.channels.cache.get(args[0]);
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            connection.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);
            connection.voice.setSelfMute(true);
        });
        message.delete();
    }
});
```

This code fot example works only when i use the `id` but not the `name` of a channel.
This is the error i get:

```
(node:5900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using discord.js v12?

Comment: nah, not really i'm using this as a selfbot so i use the library discord.js-self instead of discord.js .

Comment: Selfbots are against TOS. Please switch to normal bot accounts

Comment: alright i will, what is the answer anyway, do i need to update it to v12 or can you help me with current code, both are appreciated

Comment: You should update to v13, as it's stable right now and includes many more features